# Gnuplot does not load graph plot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot version 4.6 patch level 4.

When testing out the sample script at this link: http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html

I tried to load using the commands:

```
gnuplot
gnuplot> load 'testplotdata.p'
```

but no window was opened. Can someone please provide some guidance?

The Script and data is below.

testplotdata.p

```
# Gnuplot script file for plotting data in file "force.dat"
# This file is called   force.p
  set   autoscale                        # scale axes automatically
  unset log                              # remove any log-scaling
  unset label                            # remove any previous labels
  set xtic auto                          # set xtics automatically
  set ytic auto                          # set ytics automatically
  set title "Force Deflection Data for a Beam and a Column"
  set xlabel "Deflection (meters)"
  set ylabel "Force (kN)"
  set key at 0.01,100
  set label "Yield Point" at 0.003,260
  set arrow from 0.0028,250 to 0.003,280
  set xr [0.0:0.022]
  set yr [0:325]
  plot    "testplotdata.dat" using 1:2 title 'Column' with linespoints , \
        "testplotdata.dat" using 1:3 title 'Beam' with points
```

testplotdata.dat

```
# Force-Deflection data for a beam and a bar
# Deflection    Col-Force       Beam-Force 
0.000              0              0
0.001            104             51
0.002            202            101
0.003            298            148
0.0031           290            149
0.004            289            201
0.0041           291            209
0.005            310            250
0.010            311            260
0.020            280            240
```

Comment: Your code works out of the box for me (patchlevel 5). Does gnuplot work in other cases, e.g. just a `plot sin(x)`  either in the console or in a file which you load?

Comment: It works for me.The gnuplot on my Ubuntu 12.04 is also Version 4.6 patchlevel 4. Check if you have the terminal type wxt. You can check it by issuing the command `set terminal` to see whether the output contains wxt

Comment: It didn't contain wxt. Got gnuplot-x11 with sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11 and it worked. @DragonHu please repost as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me.The gnuplot on my Ubuntu 12.04 is also Version 4.6 patchlevel 4. Check if you have the terminal type wxt. You can check it by issuing the command `set terminal` in the gnuplot to see whether the output contains wxt. If not, please install `gnuplot-x11` package (for Debian and Ubuntu, the package name may differ for other Linux distributions.)